# Why does switching applications randomly refuse to work?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, dash-to-dock

Randomly, switching applications (`Super+Tab` by default) will refuse to work, instead a notification will fire off saying `'Desired application' is ready.`, and the icon in the dash will shake.

What causes this series of events to fire off, instead of the desired behavior?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to have been resolved by the fix linked below, though I'm not aware of how to implement it.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/merge_requests/2327